# cv2.imshow shows 9 screens instead of 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm building some code to adaptively detect skin from webcam video. I have it almost working, however, when outputting the video, it shows 9 screens of the "skin" mask instead of just one. Seems like I'm just missing something simple, but I can't figure it out.

[image shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAwPL.png)

Code below:

```
# first let's train the data
data, labels = ReadData()
classifier = TrainTree(data, labels)

# get the webcam. The input is either a video file or the camera number
# since using laptop webcam (only 1 cam), input is 0. A 2nd cam would be input 1
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # reads in the current frame
    # .read() returns True if frame read correctly, and False otherwise
    ret, frame = camera.read()   # frame.shape: (480,640,3)

    if ret:
        # reshape the frame to follow format of training data (rows*col, 3)
        data = np.reshape(frame, (frame.shape[0] * frame.shape[1], 3))
        bgr = np.reshape(data, (data.shape[0], 1, 3))
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(np.uint8(bgr), cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        # once we have converted to HSV, we reshape back to original shape of (245057,3)
        data = np.reshape(hsv, (hsv.shape[0], 3))
        predictedLabels = classifier.predict(data)

        # the AND operator applies the skinMask to the image
        # predictedLabels consists of 1 (skin) and 2 (non-skin), needs to change to 0 (non-skin) and 255 (skin)
        predictedMask = (-(predictedLabels - 1) + 1) * 255   # predictedMask.shape: (307200,)

        # resize to match frame shape
        imgLabels = np.resize(predictedMask, (frame.shape[0], frame.shape[1], 3))   # imgLabels.shape: (480,640,3)
        # masks require 1 channel, not 3, so change from BGR to GRAYSCALE
        imgLabels = cv2.cvtColor(np.uint8(imgLabels), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)   # imgLabels.shape: (480,640)

        # do bitwsie AND to pull out skin pixels. All skin pixels are anded with 255 and all others are 0
        skin = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=imgLabels) # skin.shape: (480,640,3)
        # show the skin in the image along with the mask, show images side-by-side
        # **********THE BELOW LINE OUTPUTS 9 screens of the skin mask instead of just 1  ****************
        cv2.imshow("images", np.hstack([frame, skin]))

        # if the 'q' key is pressed, stop the loop
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break
    else:
        break

# release the video capture
camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: why not print the shape of the result?

Comment: I edited my code to add the shape of each variable (see above). The predictedMask is 307200 (which is rows*cols) and the imgLabels after the resize is larger than 307200, it becomes (480,640,3). Maybe this is causing the error? However, the color channel of 3 is needed to input the imgLabels into the cvtColor BGR to GRAY. I tried changing the resize to output imgLabels as (480,640,1), and then comment out the conversion to GRAY, but then end up with this error: "error: (-215) (mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function cv::binary_op"   Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't know what to feed the classifier. But I think the method that you do to convertColor is wrong. And the program is not complete， so I cannot debug it.

Answer (score 0):

You're working with bitmaps. To get an idea what they hold, `cv2.imshow` them individually. Then you're going to see (literally) where the data goes wrong.

---

Now, the culprit is most probably `np.resize()`:

> `np.resize(a, new_shape)`
>
> Return a new array with the specified shape.
>
> If the new array is larger than the original array, **then the new array**
>   **is filled with repeated copies of `a`**.  Note that this behavior is
>   different from a.resize(new_shape) which fills with zeros instead of
>   repeated copies of `a`.

---

To *scale* a bitmap (=resize while striving to preserve the same visual image), use `cv2.resize()` as per [OpenCV: Geometric Transformations of Images](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/d6e/tutorial_py_geometric_transformations.html).

Comment: I see, however, I need the resize to shape the predictedMask into an array that is excepted by the cvtColor conversion to grayscale. I'm not sure how to go about changing the resize line to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Rachel did you read the last paragraph? Maybe the formulation was unclear.

Comment: Ah I see, I misread the last part. So my next question is that cv2.resize can resize a 1D to a 2D array giving me a (rows, cols) array. However, for cvtColor conversion to grayscale, I need to add the color channel to get (rows, cols, 3), and I'm not seeing a way to do this with cv2.resize...

Comment: @Rachel I you have a `(307200,)` array of 255's and 0's (effectively, a greyscale bitmap stretched out into a line (i guess)), you can just `np.reshape` it into the normal shape `(640,480)`. This way, it's already a good grayscale bitmap -- no need to convert it to `(640,480,3)` then back. Grayscale bitmaps only have one channel.

Comment: I thought the same as well and tried this: imgLabels = np.reshape(predictedLabels,(frame.shape[0],frame.shape[1])) and then this to assign it to 1's and 0's: imgLabels = ((-(imgLabels-1)+1)*255)  So now imgLabels.shape is (480,640) of 1's and 0's, however, I still get that error: cv2.error: ..\..\..\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:241: error: (-215) (mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function cv::binary_op   I'm really at a loss how to go about solving this.

Comment: @Rachel https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html gives an example how to paint an image over another one with a transparent color. Anyway, that seems like an unrelated problem. Is the current one solved? Is the mask now of appropriate shape, size and with expected data?

Comment: @Rachel Due to the cryptic error message, the current one seems to warrant a separate question (unless there's already an answer on the Net what it means).

Comment: I was finally able to resolve the issue. I think my imgLabels array wasn't being excepted properly as an image array. So I wrote the binary array to disk as an image, and then reopened the image as a new array. Then passed this new variable in as the mask. This ended up working. Happy it's working, but still seems like a hack-around. Maybe once I learn a bit more, I'll find a better solution. Thanks for all your help though!